# SQL count of different values in one column by date

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, pivot

I have a table that looks like:

```
os         date
--         ---
ios        2014-04-35 21:33:33 
android    2014-04-35 21:33:33
ios        2014-04-35 21:33:33
ios        2014-04-35 21:33:33
```

I want to get an output to be the counts of ios/android in each month. So like:

```
Year    Month    ios     android
2015    01       20      100
2015    02       400     20
```

Something like that.

This is what I have right now. It's not quite right though:

```
SELECT year(last_modified_date) as cy
     , month(last_modified_date) as cm
     , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM device_info WHERE os='ios')
     , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM device_info WHERE os='android')
FROM device_info
WHERE year(last_modified_date) IN (2014,2015)
GROUP BY year(last_modified_date)
       , month(last_modified_date);
```

Comment: The answers from suslov and Saharsh show we can use an expression to conditionally return a 1 or 0 (or NULL), and use a SUM aggregate function to emulate a "count" operation. If we use an expression that returns a non-null value only when a condition is true, we could use a COUNT aggregate instead of a SUM, e.g. **`COUNT(IF(os='ios',os,NULL))`** NOTE: the predicate in the WHERE clause isn't sargable. We usually prefer predicates of a form that can make use of a range scan operation on a available index, e.g. **`WHERE last_modified_date >= '2014-01-01' and last_modified_date < '2016-01-01'`**.

Answer (score 2):

Tru this:

```
SELECT YEAR(di.date) AS 'Year', 
       MONTH(di.date) AS 'Month', 
       SUM(di.os = 'ios') AS 'ios', 
       SUM(di.os = 'android') AS 'android'
FROM device_info AS di
GROUP BY YEAR(di.date), MONTH(di.date);
```

Comment: Bas karo DBA saheb.. bau agal nikli gya tame to.. Amari par krupa karo ne... :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation with `case` expression:

```
select year(`last_modified_date`) as `Year`
     , month(`last_modified_date`) as `Month`
     , sum(`os` = 'ios') as `ios`
     , sum(`os` = 'android') as `android`
from `device_info`
where year(`last_modified_date`) in (2014, 2015)
group by year(`last_modified_date`)
       , month(`last_modified_date`);
```